# If $A$ is a linear map, then $A(\alpha(t))'=A(\alpha'(t))$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $A:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^3$ be a linear map. I need the following technical result to solve a problem I'm solving:

$$A(\alpha(t))'=A(\alpha'(t))$$

Where $\alpha:I\to \mathbb R^3$ is a parametric curve.

Intuitively, I know this is true, but I would like to prove it formally.

Comment: Use the chain rule.

Comment: @anomaly I did. See: $(A\circ \alpha)'(t)=A'(\alpha(t))\circ\alpha'(t)=A(\alpha(t))\circ\alpha'(t)$ I still don't get what I want.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question.  I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: @user42912: That does get you want you want. Note that $A' = A$ is constant.

Comment: @anomaly I see, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $T$ be the derivative of $A \circ \alpha$, evaluated at a given $t \in I$.  Then $T$ is the unique linear map $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that

$$\frac{||A \circ \alpha(t + h) - A \circ \alpha(t) - T(h)||}{|h|}$$

goes to zero as $h$ goes to $0$.  Let $S: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be the linear map $S(h) = A(\alpha'(t)h)$.  Then

$$\frac{||A \circ \alpha(t + h) - A \circ \alpha(t) - S(h)||}{|h|} = \frac{||A[ \alpha(t + h) -  \alpha(t) - \alpha'(t)h]||}{|h|}$$

where $|| \cdot ||$ is a fixed norm on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

The numerator is bounded by $||A|| \cdot ||\alpha(t+h) - \alpha(t) - \alpha'(t)h||$, where $||A||$ is the norm of the linear transformation $A$, and by definition of $\alpha'(t)$,

$$\frac{||\alpha(t+h)-\alpha(t) -\alpha'(t)h||}{|h|}$$

goes to zero as $h$ goes to $0$.  So $S$ satisfies the same property as $T$.  By uniqueness, $S = T$.

**Another way using the chain rule**:

The chain rule says that the derivative of $A \circ \alpha$, evaluated at $t$, is the composition of the linear transformation $\alpha'(t): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ (the derivative of $\alpha$ evaluated at $t$), followed by the linear transformation $A'(\alpha(t)): \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ (the derivative of $A$ evaluated at $\alpha(t)$).  So

$$(A \circ \alpha)'(t) = A'(\alpha(t)) \circ \alpha'(t)$$

Since $A$ is a linear transformation, its derivative at every point of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is constant and equal to $A$.  Thus

$$(A \circ \alpha)(t) = A \circ \alpha'(t)$$

as linear maps $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: So you proved the derivative of the composition $A(\alpha(t))'$ is $A(\alpha'(t)\alpha(t))$, but I need that the derivative of this composition were $A(\alpha'(t))$, can we say $A(\alpha'(t)\alpha(t))=A(\alpha'(t))$?

Comment: I wrote it wrong, it should be correct now.  If by $A(\alpha'(t))$, you mean the linear transformation $A \circ \alpha'(t): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, then that's correct.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry, I still don't get it. Isn't the derivative of a linear transformation the linear trasnformation itself, i.e., $A'=A$? so shouldn't we have $A(\alpha(t))'=A(\alpha(t))$?

Comment: The derivative of $A$ at any point is $A$ itself, yes.  For the derivative of $A \circ \alpha$, you need to use the chain rule, which is basically what I did.

Comment: Using the chain rule as you said: $(A\circ \alpha)'(t)=A'(\alpha(t))\circ\alpha'(t)=A(\alpha(t))\circ\alpha'(t)$ I still don't get what I want. What am I missing?

Comment: If $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, then the derivative $ f': \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \textrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ is a function which associates to each point $p \in \mathbb{R}^3$ a certain linear map $f'(p): \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$.  If $f$ is already a linear map, then $f'(p) = f$ for all $p \in \mathbb{R}^3$.  So $A'(\alpha(t)) = A$.

Comment: So what you wrote: $A(\alpha(t)) = A'(\alpha(t))$ does not make sense; the right side is a linear map, the left side is an element of $\mathbb{R}^3$.  It should be $A = A'(\alpha(t))$.  See my edit.

Comment: Haaaaaaaaa, I got it!!! Thank you very very much!!!!!!!!!